# Why don't flask signals work with lambdas?

Tags: python, flask, lambda

This works:

```
from flask import Flask, request_started

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

def echo(sender, **extra):
    return print('request_started')

request_started.connect(echo)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'index page'
```

while this doesn't:

```
from flask import Flask, request_started

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

request_started.connect(lambda sender, **extra: print('request_started'))

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'index page'
```

Why is that?

the first outputs correctly while the lambda gives nothing i.e. no errors.

I'm using python 3.6

Apparently, it has nothing to do with the `print` function, I also tried this and it didn't work out.

```
request_started.connect(lambda sender, **extra: open('output', 'w').write('request_started\n'))
```

**~ UPDATE ~**

Now, this works and I'm confused !

```
echo = lambda sender, **extra: print('request_started')
request_started.connect(echo)
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: Just there is no output in case of lambda, unlike the regular function which outputs the message properly.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't work because the lambda does not accept the correct arguments? Try `lambda sender:`.

Comment: I've already done that, and it didn't work either

Comment: I'm using python 3.6

Comment: I'm not familiar with flask and originally thought this was something with lambda syntax independent of flask. The dupe I posted originally was only related to python 2. Perhaps flask redirects the output to a log file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Flask signals](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/signals/) are implemented using the *blinker* library: https://pythonhosted.org/blinker/index.html#blinker.base.Signal.connect

The signature of the `connect` function is:

```
 connect(receiver, sender=ANY, weak=True)
```

With the documentation saying the following about the `weak` parameter:

> **weak** – If true, the Signal will hold a weakref to receiver and
>   automatically disconnect when receiver goes out of scope or is garbage
>   collected. Defaults to True

Since your first example uses the default parameter of `True` and there is no other reference to the `lambda` it is automatically disconnected again after the call `request_started.connect(lambda sender, **extra: print('request_started'))` is finished.

In the second version

```
echo = lambda sender, **extra: print('request_started')
request_started.connect(echo)
```

you keep a reference to the `lambda` in the variable `echo` so the signal is connected until `echo` goes out of scope (and is garbage collected)

Comment: Thank you! I've already figured it out a few seconds before your answer, but thanks anyway.